# How to combine the use of %in% with OR operator?

Tags: r, operators

I would like to look up and test whether values from one set ("set A") appear in *either* set B *or* set C. I was trying to use the `%in%` operator for this purpose, but couldn't figure out how to combine it with OR.

A reproducible example follows at the bottom, but just the gist of what I'm trying to get is something like:

```
set_a %in% (set_b | set_c)
```

where I want to know which values from **set_a** exist in either **set_b** or **set_c**, or in both.

### Example

```r
#Step 1 :: Creating the data

    set_a <- unlist(strsplit("Eden Kendall Cali Ari Madden Leo Stacy Emmett Marco Bridger Alissa Elijah Bryant Pierre Sydney Luis", split=" "))

    set_b <- as.data.table(unlist(strsplit("Kathy Ryan Brice Rowan Nina Abram Miles Kristina Gabriel Madden Jasper Emmett Marco Bridger Alissa Elijah Bryant Pierre Sydney Luis", split=" ")))
    set_c <- as.data.table(unlist(strsplit("Leo Stacy Emmett Marco Moriah Nola Jorden Dalia Kenna Laney Dillon Trystan Elijah Bryant Pierr", split=" ")))


    NamesList <- list(set_b, set_c) #set_b and set_c will now become neighboring data.table dataframes in one list.
    > NamesList
    [[1]]
              V1
     1:    Kathy
     2:     Ryan
     3:    Brice
     4:    Rowan
     5:     Nina
     6:    Abram
     7:    Miles
     8: Kristina
     9:  Gabriel
    10:   Madden
    11:   Jasper
    12:   Emmett
    13:    Marco
    14:  Bridger
    15:   Alissa
    16:   Elijah
    17:   Bryant
    18:   Pierre
    19:   Sydney
    20:     Luis

    [[2]]
             V1
     1:     Leo
     2:   Stacy
     3:  Emmett
     4:   Marco
     5:  Moriah
     6:    Nola
     7:  Jorden
     8:   Dalia
     9:   Kenna
    10:   Laney
    11:  Dillon
    12: Trystan
    13:  Elijah
    14:  Bryant
    15:   Pierr

#Step 2 :: Checking which values from set_a appear in either set_b or set_c

    matches <- set_a %in% (set_b | set_c)
    #doesn't work!
```

Any ideas? By the way, it is important to me to use a data.table format.

Comment: Try them separately `set_a %in% set_b | set_a %in%  set_c` Or use `union` , `set_a %in% union(set_b, set_c)`

Comment: You can simply rbind the two lists, i.e. `set_a %in% rbindlist(NamesList)$V1`

Comment: @RonakShah's answer is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the conditions separately

```
set_a %in% set_b | set_a %in% set_c
```

Or use `union` or `unique`

```
set_a %in% union(set_b, set_c)

set_a %in% unique(c(set_b, set_c))
```

Comment: I ended up using the `union()` solution. However, in my data (also provided in the example above), both set_b and set_c have a header called _V1_. Hence, the code is: `set_a %in% union(set_b$V1, set_c$V1)`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
Reduce(`|`, lapply(list(set_b, set_c), `%in%`, set_a))
```

Comment: I get this: `Warning message:
In f(init, x[[i]]) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`